# Abuse report for spamming...abuse report

Tags: email-server, spam, isp, abuse, report

Few weeks ago, i activated on my server on automatic abuse report mail when someone try to brute force my SSH, i did it because i got an average of 3000 spamming IP each weeks.

But today, my ISP send me a mail saying that someone is reporting me for mail spamming. I checked all the activity of my server to check that i haven't any mail sent except abuse mails. I disabled this feature while this case is not resolved.

Anyone know what the law say about this? Is an abuse report mail can be assimilated to a spam?

EDIT : The main question is if an abuse report (XARF) sent to the abuse mailbox of an ISP can be assimilated to a SPAM. And in the case of this is the reason of the complain (my server was not corrupted), what can i do.

Comment: The two may be entirely unrelated. Ask your ISP for further details. The law is irrelevant here, really.

Comment: I am actually waiting for an answer from them

Comment: I would make sure your config is secure too, to be sure your server dont act as a relay

Comment: How can i check this, i remember that i don't accept to be a relay. But in the case of i made an error, how can i check that. Also, my ISP impose to use they relay and be authenticated to send mail, then, if someone want to send a mail from my server, he is imposed to go trough my postfix server. And i didn't find any trace of other mail in my logs.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider logging the IP in a file somewhere instead of sending an email for each attempt, because that's a lot of e-mail and may be against your ISP's term of service.

I recommend using [Fail2ban](http://fail2ban.org) to ban the source IP after too much failed attempts.

Comment: It's exactly what i do, and after too many attempts, i ban them for a week and send a mail to the ISP of the IP, the mail sent is a XARF report (http://xarf.org/). Generally i got a thank you mail for reporting them, and often some news about the resolution of the case.